# Is self reference of a variable a bad thing in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
function Model() {
  //constructor
}

var dummy = new Model(); // create an instance of Model
dummy.self = dummy;
```

Here we have an instance of the class Model, that is just one object in memory as I know. The **`dummy`** variable is a reference to the object in memory, the **`self`** property is a reference to that same object too.

Are this code creating just two references to the object itself? One the **`dummy`** variable and the second the **`self`** property?.

If you inspect that code in Chrome Dev tool, as expected the console show you nested references to the infinite.

**Does this have implications for the performance of the code??**

#### NOTE:

As a reference I have a class that returns a instance when created and each method return a promise. Finally when the promise is resolved, the instance class is the resolved object.

```
var model = new Model();
var promise = model.$save();

// when resolved
promise.$$state.value === model;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There is no performance lag. You are just storing one more property to object. The Chrome Dev Tools infinite reference because every time you expands an object it explores it. In this case object you are expanding an object with reference to itself.